# Interlinking two option groups in MS Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two option groups with frames on a form: *Packing* and *Pallet*. *Packing* contains 3 values: *Box, Rack* and *Pallet*. I wish to connect the frames such that if a person clicks on *Pallet* option in *Packing* Frame, the *Pallet* frame activates and remains deactivated for the remaining two options.

```
Private Sub Frame_Packing_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
   If Frame_Packing.Value = 3 Then
      Frame_Palet.Locked = False
   End If
End Sub
```

I tried this code, but it only works once. So, if I click on *Pallet* the *Pallet* frame gets unlocked but if I change the value to *Box*, it doesn't deactivate. I want the *Pallet* frame to be active only when the pallet option is active under the *Packing* frame.

By frame I mean Option Group, which has option boxes underneath it. For example, *Gender*, you can either Select *MALE* or *FEMALE*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an *Else* condition to deactivate the lock:

```
Private Sub Frame_Packing_AfterUpdate()
   If Frame_Packing.Value = 3 Then
      Me.Dirty = False
      Frame_Palet.Locked = False
   Else
      Frame_Palet.Locked = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't work the way I want it to work after using the else statement. After adding the else statement, if I click on Pallet (Packing Frame) the Palet frame gets activated (Which is what I want) but when I click on Box again it gives me a run time error saying "You can't lock control while it has unsaved changes" instead of deactivating the Pallet Frame.

Comment: Try the `AfterUpdate` event of the control.

Comment: See edit using `Me.Dirty = False` to save form changes getting it out of edit mode.